# how to use variables in the same file for a other piece of code

Tags: c#

I am making a little code, and I am now already running into a error

```
string getCode(string code)
{
    int count = code.Length;
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        string error = "no";
    }
    else
    {
        string error = "yes";
        string error_message = "There is something wrong with the code. Program.cs - line 23";
    }

    if (error == "yes")
        return null;

    return error;
}
```

Well, now I am setting the variable `error` in a if statement. Bu if I later say `if (error == "yes")` doesn't work. It gives me the error `the name 'error' does not exist in the current content`
I am now already search whole the internet for 15-20 minutes. Tryin a lot of fixes and examples. With global variables and even tried to make another class for my variables and read the variables from there. That worked, but then I could not set the variables anymore. Or I just don't know how to do so. Can you please help me? I will be really thankful!

Thanks

Comment: C or C#? Those are two ***very*** different languages!

Comment: The scope of `error` needs to be before the `if` and the same level as the `int count`. Also this is not C so should not be tagged as such.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude its c#

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Doesn't work..

Comment: The scope of a declared variable is limited to the enclosing braces `{ }`. I.e. your codes declares 2 distinct `error` variables. One in `if () { ... }` and another in `else { ...}`. And there is no `error` variable in scope after `if else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the `error` variable out of the scope of `if`, like below:

```
string error = null;
if (count % 2 == 0)
{
    error = "no";
}
else
{
    error = "yes";
    string error_message = "There is something wrong with the code. Program.cs - line 23";
}

if (error == "yes")
    return null;
```

Doing so, you could access this variable either in the block of `if` or in the block of `else` or more generally speaking in all scopes that would be enclosed in the scope of method `getCode`.

*side note:* `error_message` can only be used in the block of `else`, and there you just declare a variable and you assign a value to it. You probably have to move also this declaration next to the declaration of `error`.

Comment: This doesn't change anything, it only gives another error... See screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/jsydva)

Comment: @20Host.nl When you declare a variable, you can't re-declare in any enclosing scope. In simple terms, when you declare the variable `error` in the body of `getCode` method, you can't re-declare it in the statements of an `if` block, or of a `for` block etc.

Comment: you have to assign a value to error from beginning, otherwise you'll get 
error: Use of unassigned local variable 'error'

Comment: I personally suggest you to read the following to improve your understanding of the scope of variables. https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-24-understanding-variable-scope

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variables out of the scope to be accessible by the whole code,
like

```
string error="";
string getCode(string code)
            {
                int count = code.Length;
                if (count % 2 == 0)
                {
                    error = "no";
                }
                else
                {
                    error = "yes";
                    string error_message = "There is something wrong with the code. Program.cs - line 23";
                }

                if (error == "yes")
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Now the `if (error == "yes")` doesn't give any error anymore. But the rest now does... See screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/jsyeg9)

Comment: Read my code carefully. You have to remove the declaration from the whole code ! the rest will be just : error="Yes"; not string error = "Yes";

Comment: @20Host.nl: writing a type name (here `string`) before a variable name makes it a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the variable *global* by creating a class and then calling the class when needing to use this to do this create a class like below:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static String error = "yes"; 
}
```

you can add anymore variables to that when needed to call it use

```
global.error
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
string getCode(string code)
        {
            int count = code.Length;
            string error = "";
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                error = "no";
            }
            else
            {
                error = "yes";
                string error_message = "There is something wrong with the code. Program.cs - line 23";
            }

            if (error == "yes")
            return null;
        }
```

What you need to know is that if you declare a variable inside a scope, it is visible inside that scope only.
Curly braces define a scope so your error variables were visible inside your if true branch and else branch being two different variables with same name in different scopes.

The changed code moved *error* variable declaration into containing method scope (getCode) making it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string getCode(string code)
        {
            int count = code.Length;
            string error = null;
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                error = "no";
            }
            else
            {
                error = "yes";                    
            }

            if (error == "yes")
                return "something that you intended to return when there is an error";
            else
                return "something that you intended to return when there is no error";
        }
```